# Google Maps API: How to get draggable map with static pin at centre and get location of this pin each time map is moved

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

Need to implement a simple draggable map (no zoom), the pin should stay static in the centre, overlaying the map. Every time the map is moved/dragged under the static pin the positioning details of the pin are updated and I can grab those positioning details and display the address in input field above.

Probably a very simple task, I just don't have any experience with Google maps and it would be great if someone could point me either to a working example of this or to right API's/Libraries that  I can use in my HTML5/Angular app. Would save me a lot of time researching. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You can re-center the marker in a `dragend` event, and grab the new lat/long.  If you want to convert the lat/long to a real world address, you can pass them to a reverse geocoder.

```js
var newlat, newlong;

var latitude = 51.5;
var longitude = -0.12;
var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 8,
  center: coords,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map = new google.maps.Map(
  document.getElementById("mapContainer"), mapOptions
);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: coords,
  map: map,
  draggable: true,
});
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend',
  function() {
    marker.setPosition(map.getCenter());
    newlat = marker.getPosition().lat();
    newlong = marker.getPosition().lng();

    $('#coords').html(newlat + ', ' + newlong);
  })
```

```css
#mapContainer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}
#coords {
  width: 380px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="mapContainer"></div>
<br>
<div id="coords"></div>
```